# Redme Note Confuguring with ubuntu 14

Tags: 14.04, mount, permissions

I have just got a Redme note and using ubuntu 14.04. I can't transfer the media with my laptop. The phone is a android 4.2 and i want to transfer my media from my laptop to the redme note but its not detecting as a device or storage drive. I tried with help provided with the phone but failed.

**The phone help mentions 
1) Use the install tool "sudo aptitude install mtpfs libfuse-dev libmad0-dev"
2) Create a directory "mkdir"/media/mtp
3) Confirm user group permissions in current fuse user group
4) Sign in again
5) Access mounted device mtpfs/media/mtp via File explore; same as local directory
6) Uninstall device Fusemount-u/media/mtp
(Ubuntu 8.04)**

I tried the step 1 and it does some thing but step 2 and others dont work.

***I am a very basic computer user and have no knowledge in command line. Please help in a step by step guide so i can got my phone work with my laptop.***

*I have just found that the same device is recognized in linux mint 17 desktop of one of my friend and i installed 17.1, but still its not recognized in my lenovo B560 laptop, and i have now freshly installed ubuntu 14.01 32 bit in my laptop, and updated to date, still its not recognizing device in file mode, but if i change to photo mode it recognize as a camera device only, shows the photo folder only of my android device. It is recgnised on a windows 7 partition, so no cable fault.*

**please help to solve the problem**

Comment: Phone? Please edit your question to provide some information about what it is you want to do, what you want to do it with, etc.

Comment: The phone is a android 4.2 and i want to transfer my media from my laptop to the redme note but its not detecting as a  device or storage drive.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to connect my redmi 1s directly w/o an issue. It was available in Devices in Nautilus.

I will suggest you to update your ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Or simply run Software Updater and update ubuntu base and drivers.

Comment: i have the latest 14.04 and updated till date. i cant find the device in devices. can you tell me how to achive step 3, i.e. 3) Confirm user group permissions in current fuse user group . I have make a mnt in media but how to change permission.

Comment: @AUROKUMAR: Those instructions are extremely old and are no longer required in Ubuntu 14.04LTS. Did you try following those instructions before you connected your device?

Comment: I agree with Jo and I suggest you to try with another cable as all cables are not meant for data transfers. Alternatively to test your phones port try to connect an OTG.

Comment: I have just found that the same device is recognized in linux mint 17 desktop of one of my friend and i installed 17.1, but still its not recognized in my lenovo B560 laptop, and i have now freshly installed ubuntu 14.01 32 bit in my laptop, and updated to date, still its not recognizing device in file mode, but if i change to photo mode it recognize as a camera device only, shows the photo folder only of my android device.   It is recgnised on a windows 7 partition, so no cable fault. please help to solve the problem